# How to migrate/copy an existing www. level cookie to a wildcard *. cookie. in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Currently our Rails application has a session cookie saved at as a www. level cookie. (ie [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), as we are now using multiple subdomains I'm trying to find a way to essentially copy the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) cookie and save the data from it in *.example.com

I'm ideally looking for a solution that requires no additional action from the user (such as forcing everyone to log out and log back in again)

We're using Ruby 2.7.4 and Rails 5.2.6

Comment: I don't think it has much to do with rails, you can set it with JS function `setcookie`, see https://webrewrite.com/setting-cookies-for-multiple-subdomains/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a transition period:

###### Period A (now):

Always read and write a cookie on `www.`

###### Period B (now):

If the user doesn't have the `*.` cookie, read the `www.` and write in a cookie `*.`, delete the `www.` one.

###### Period C (after):

You're reading and writing a cookie on *.exemple.com

Comment: This sounds ideal! What are the functions/methods I use to read the www. cookie and then to write the *. cookie?

Comment: just `cookies` like you did, but name the two cookies with different names

Answer (score 0):

A simple `before_action` copying all values should work:

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :copy_cookie_values_to_root_domain

private

def copy_cookie_values_to_root_domain
  cookies.each do |(key, value)|
    cookies[key] = { value: value, domain: :all }
  end
end
```

Internally the cookie is prepared and processed on each request anyway. Therefore I would not optimize this method any further. Please keep in mind that you need to have a similar block for `signed` cookies too then you use them. See docs for [Cookies in Rails](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).